Algorithm that finds roots of nilpotent matrices (when they exist)?
I'm curious about automatically calculating roots
B=ⁿ⎷A, where n is an integer larger than 1, and A is a square nilpotent matrix. I.e. find at least one square matrix B such that Bⁿ=A, or report that no such B exists.
Nilpotent matrices only have roots in special circumstances. For example, if A = {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{1,0,0}} is a 3 × 3 matrix with A₂₀=1 and Aᵢⱼ=0 otherwise (row major zero-indexing convention), then the matrix B = {{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,1,0}} satisfies B² = A and B is a square root of A.
The conditions for nilpotent matrices to have a square root are outlined in this mathematics stack exchange answer.
Does anyone know the name of algorithms that handle the general case?
(well-tested implementations further welcome).
